# How to select document body in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple vue component that will display a preloader when some images are loaded or changes. It's working fine, but I'm not able to disable the overflow of the document body when the component is displayed. Is there a way in Javascript to select the body and set the overflow to hidden? I'm not expert in vanilla javascript.

Comment: To get the body just use `document.body`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` to select any item in your DOM.  Here is the [mdn_link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for details

If you want to select the `body` then simply you can use `document.body`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will use it. I'm trying now using `document.getElementsByTagName('body').css.overflow = 'hidden';` but I'm not sure if this the best way.

Comment: @guggio `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not a single element. Also, you cannot use `.css` on a DOM element.

Comment: @VLAZ ok, so how I apply a  css rule to the body with JS?

Comment: @guggio https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style

Comment: You can simple do this `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";`

or `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'`

Comment: @SifatHaque normally your suggestion works fine, but I have a `Cannot set property 'overflow' of undefined` error in concole when the vue component is mounted :( !!

Comment: You can use `onload` to check if body is loaded or not and then do your stuff. You can study this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload